# Convert to simple date format or Unix time stamp date in android?

Tags: parsing, date

I am getting date (**2015-03-20T06:34:01.831183+01:00**) from server which is not simple date format i want to convert this type of date to simple date format like (**yyyyMMddHHmmssSSSS**)

How can i do this.
I have used this but not working for me

```
String tdate="2015-03-15T14:04:43.877593+01:00";        
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss a");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
    String dateInString = "2015-03-15T14:04:43.877593+01:00";       

    try {

        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
        System.out.println("System Date in GMT: "+formatDateToString(date, "yyyyMMddHHmmssSSSS", "IST"));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

> Error Logcat

```
03-19 12:51:39.222: W/System.err(32124): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-03-15T14:04:43.877593+01:00" (at offset 19)
03-19 12:51:39.228: W/System.err(32124):    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:555)
03-19 12:51:39.228: W/System.err(32124):    at com.example.xmldatademo.XmlActivity.onCreate(XmlActivity.java:51)
03-19 12:51:39.228: W/System.err(32124):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
03-19 12:51:39.228: W/System.err(32124):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
03-19 12:51:39.229: W/System.err(32124):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
03-19 12:51:39.229: W/System.err(32124):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
03-19 12:51:39.229: W/System.err(32124):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
03-19 12:51:39.229: W/System.err(32124):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
03-19 12:51:39.229: W/System.err(32124):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-19 12:51:39.230: W/System.err(32124):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-19 12:51:39.230: W/System.err(32124):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
03-19 12:51:39.230: W/System.err(32124):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 12:51:39.230: W/System.err(32124):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-19 12:51:39.231: W/System.err(32124):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
03-19 12:51:39.231: W/System.err(32124):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
03-19 12:51:39.231: W/System.err(32124):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-19 12:51:39.231: I/System.out(32124): null
03-19 12:51:39.233: D/AndroidRuntime(32124): Shutting down VM
03-19 12:51:39.233: W/dalvikvm(32124): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416a5d40)
03-19 12:51:39.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32124): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 12:51:39.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32124): Process: com.example.xmldatademo, PID: 32124
03-19 12:51:39.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32124): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.xmldatademo/com.example.xmldatademo.XmlActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 12:51:39.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32124):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
03-19 12:51:39.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32124):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
03-19 12:51:39.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32124):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
03-19 12:51:39.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32124):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
03-19 12:51:39.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32124):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-19 12:51:39.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32124):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-19 12:51:39.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32124):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
03-19 12:51:39.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32124):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 12:51:39.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32124):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-19 12:51:39.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32124):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
03-19 12:51:39.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32124):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
03-19 12:51:39.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32124):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-19 12:51:39.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32124): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 12:51:39.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32124):    at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1183)
03-19 12:51:39.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32124):    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.formatImpl(SimpleDateFormat.java:518)
03-19 12:51:39.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32124):    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:818)
03-19 12:51:39.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32124):    at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:307)
03-19 12:51:39.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32124):    at com.example.xmldatademo.XmlActivity.onCreate(XmlActivity.java:56)
03-19 12:51:39.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32124):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
03-19 12:51:39.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32124):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
03-19 12:51:39.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32124):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
03-19 12:51:39.235: E/AndroidRuntime(32124):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out. Hope this will help. I am not reading fraction seconds(SSS).

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
        String dateInString = "2015-03-15T14:04:43.877593+01:00";

        SimpleDateFormat newDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSSS");

        Date date = null;
        try {
            //date instace
            date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
            //date format -> yyyyMMddHHmmssSSSS
            String sNewDate = newDateFormat.format(date);
            System.out.println("New  Date Format " + sNewDate);
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```